# Como pegar tempo por milisegundo?

Tags: lua, time

Gostaria de pegar o tempo (HH:MM:SS) por milissegundo.

Ex: 86400000

Ficaria: `24:00:00` já que é o equivalente a um dia.

Comment: É dado `86400000` e você quer `24:00:00` ou vice-versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Até onde eu sei não é possível diretamente em Lua. O mais próximo que conseguiria é usar o `os.clock()` mas a precisão é menor. Entretanto posso sugerir algumas opções:

- criar uma função em C e usar a API de  interoperabilidade para expô-la ao *script* Lua. Um exemplo pode ser encontrado nessa [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10168228).
- usar uma biblioteca externa que contenha uma função que faça isto. Pode usar a [LuaSocket](https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket) e fazer `socket.gettime() * 1000`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/Conceptual.md).